# How to create a copy text link?

Tags: html, jquery

I created a code and I want the visitor to be able to copy the BTC address `<small type="text" id="copy-to-clipboard">{{ group.field_groupe_donation.value }}</small>` by clicking on the fontawesome icon `<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="copyText()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>`.

How to do this ?

```js
(function($) {

  function copyText() {
    var text = document.getElementById("copy-to-clipboard");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + text.value);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-donation text-justify">
  <div>Si le contenu de ce groupe vous plait, vous pouvez faire un don à son l'auteur en Bitcoin (BTC).</div>
  <div class="h3"><i class="fab fa-bitcoin fa-lg btc"></i> Adresse BTC :</div>
  {{ content.field_groupe_donation }}
  <small type="text" id="copy-to-clipboard">{{ group.field_groupe_donation.value }}</small>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="copyText()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>
  <div class="mt-3 text-center">
    <a href="/node/310"> <b>Comment ça marche ?</b></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

It does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the clipboard API for this. Please note that this requires your site to run in a secure context (https or localhost).

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('bar').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (window.isSecureContext && 'clipboard' in navigator) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementById('foo').textContent);
    } else {
      console.error(`Clipboard API requires secure context or your browser doesn't support clipboard API`);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<small id="foo">This text should be in your clipboard after clicking the copy button</small>
<br />
<button id="bar" type="button">copy</button>
<br />
<textarea placeholder="try pasting here after clicking copy button" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
```

As with most things, in 2020 you want to be using the browser API and not jQuery.

Comment: Your example does not work. It does not copy anything https://ibb.co/qdpH5jm and https://ibb.co/dctKLdY

Comment: Check the snippet here with either Firefox or Chrome. It does work. Did you check the console? Is the site running in a secure context as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Everything is OK but it does not work. I copied and pasted some code into a JS file is this good https://pastebin.com/cRHvP0WK ?

Comment: Looks clean except the `<` is missing in the opening `button` tag. You might want to add a `console.log('clicklistener executed')` in your click event listener for the button. Are you dynamically creating the button via JS?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is my file correct ? https://pastebin.com/urfJ5smd

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your code, I propose to create the "copyText" function in this way.

```
  function copyText() {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($("#copy-to-clipboard").text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
      alert('Copied');
    }
```

The instruction `document.execCommand("copy");` allows you to copy all the elements of the DOM you have selected using the .select() function.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I updated my question along with your answer. Is it still valid ?

Comment: I just changed the code, take a look and check if it works for you.